# LINQ: Doing an order by!

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf

i have some Linq to Entity code like so:

```
var tablearows = Context.TableB.Include("TableA").Where(c => c.TableBID == 1).Select(c => c.TableA).ToList();
```

So i'm returning the results of TableA with TableB.TableBID = 1

That's all good

Now how can I sort TableA by one of its column? There is a many to many relation ship between the two tables

I tried various ways with no look, for example

```
var tablearows = Context.TableB.Include("TableA").Where(c => c.TableBID == 1).Select(c => c.TableA).OrderBy(p => p.ColumnToSort).ToList();
```

In the above case when i type "p." i don't have access to the columns from TableA, presumably because it's a collection of TableA objects, not a single row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using SelectMany instead of Select  :

```
var tablearows = Context.TableB.Include("TableB")
     .Where(c => c.TableBID == 1)
     .SelectMany(c => c.TableA)
     .OrderBy(p => p.ColumnToSort)
     .ToList();
```

**EDIT :** 
The expression below returns collection of TableAs -every element of the collection is an instance of TableA collection not TableA instance- (that's why you can't get the properties of the TableA) :

```
var tablearows = Context.TableB.Include("TableB")
     .Where(c => c.TableBID == 1)
     .Select(c => c.TableA);
```

If we turn the Select to SelectMany, we get the result as one concatenated collection that includes elements :

```
var tablearows = Context.TableB.Include("TableB")
     .Where(c => c.TableBID == 1)
     .SelectMany(c => c.TableA);
```

Comment: Great, that worked. So can i ask exactly what the difference is and why that worked?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so now I've taken on board that there's a many to many relationship, I think Canavar is right - you want a `SelectMany`.

Again, that's easier to see in a query expression:

```
var tableARows = from rowB in Context.TableB.Include("TableA")
                 where rowB.TableBID == 1
                 from rowA in rowB.TableA
                 orderby rowA.ColumnToSort
                 select rowA;
```

The reason it didn't work is that you've got a different result type. Previously, you were getting a type like:

```
List<EntitySet<TableA>>
```

(I don't know the exact type as I'm not a LINQ to Entities guy, but it would be something like that.)

Now we've flattened all those TableA rows into a single list:

```
List<TableA>
```

Now you can't order a sequence of *sets* by a single column within a row - but you can order a sequence of *rows* by a column. So basically your intuition in the question was right when you said "presumably because it's a collection of TableA objects, not a single row" - but it wasn't quite clear what you mean by "it".

Now, is that flattening actually appropriate for you? It means you no longer know which B contributed any particular A. Is there only actually one B involved here, so it doesn't matter? If so, there's another option which *may* even perform better (I really don't know, but you might like to look at the SQL generated in each case and profile it):

```
var tableARows = Context.TableB.Include("TableA")
                        .Where(b => b.TableBID == 1)
                        .Single()
                        .TableA.OrderBy(a => a.ColumnToSort)
                        .ToList();
```

Note that this will fail (or at least would in LINQ to Objects; I don't know exactly what will happen in entities) if there *isn't* a row in table B with an ID of 1. Basically it selects the single row, then selects all As associated with that row, and orders them.

Comment: Great, that worked. So can i ask exactly what the difference is and why that worked? p.s. i asked Canavar the same Q